# getUserMedia frozen at first frame on Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, camera, getusermedia

I have a working code on desktop browsers supporting getUserMedia Api, I can correctly see a video preview of my webcam in the div `videoPreview`. However, when running on Android device, this same code takes a picture with my front camera when I accept to share it in Chrome browser, then the preview keeps frozen on this first frame.

```
navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getMedia(
        // constraints
        {video:true, audio:false},

        // success callback
        function (mediaStream) {
            var video = document.getElementById('videoPreview');
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
            video.play();
        },   
        //handle error
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
```

Comment: Just add autoplay attribute to <video> tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For those encountering same problem : I fixed it by adding `autoplay` attribute to my `<video>` tag.

Was stuck with this for a while, I hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine and myself had the same issue today: working code didn't work anymore and the camera was frozen. Surprisingly (or not), a reboot fixed that problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping but already tried that and it didn't fixed the problem for me :/ May I ask if you are using a similar code ?

Comment: We use this code:
https://github.com/pixelpark/webgl-cardboard-boilerplate
or more specifically:
https://github.com/pixelpark/webgl-cardboard-boilerplate/blob/master/js/videosetup.js

The setup is a bit more complex because we have a cardboard stereo view.