# mdg:camera fail to play video on Android + chrome because video.play() is not binded on user event

Tags: meteor, html5-video, getusermedia

My MeteorJS application just needs to start the smartphone camera to allow the user to take photos. 
It used to work, but when i used it recently it refused to start the video stream and display in the console :

```
Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

The application use mdg:camera package throught this fork that fix a stream error since Chrome 45 (https://github.com/perak/meteor-camera/)

The video.play() methods is called on Template rendering which can explain the recent error. So i'm looking for a solution to resolve this.

To reproduce this:

- meteor create reproduce-camera-bug
- cd reproduce-camera-bug && mkdir packages
- clone the https://github.com/perak/meteor-camera/
- edit reproduce-camera-bug.html and add {{> camera}}
- Configure your nginx as a proxy (config here https://gist.github.com/Rebolon/dd3d72eacf2bd1d6d3ae)
- Start nginx and start meteor
- Open Chrome on your android device and go to the url where your app is running : https://myComputerIP
- Test the app and see that the video is not running, but instead you have a photo...

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Following this thread " [getUserMedia frozen at first frame on Android Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30524749/getusermedia-frozen-at-first-frame-on-android-chrome) " it seems that adding attributes autoplay to the video node is the right thing to do.